# Filtros en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un Array `Data`:

```
var Data = [{"Nombre": "A","Apellido": "B","Edad": 12},{},{},{},...]
```

¿Cómo puedo filtrar los datos para que me dé como resultado todos los que tengan *`Apellido`* igual a *`B`* por ejemplo?

Comment: `Data` **no es un JSON**, es una variable JavaScript

Comment: Puse un ejemplo X, creo que la idea se entiende

Comment: Una especificación mas correcta seria decir tengo un array de Objetos javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Del siguiente código:

```js
var Data = [{"Nombre": "AA","Apellido": "B","Edad": 12},{"Nombre": "BA","Apellido": "C","Edad": 12},{"Nombre": "CA","Apellido": "D","Edad": 12},{"Nombre": "DA","Apellido": "E","Edad": 12},{"Nombre": "EA","Apellido": "F","Edad": 12},{"Nombre": "GA","Apellido": "G","Edad": 12},{"Nombre": "HA","Apellido": "B","Edad": 12},{"Nombre": "IA","Apellido": "B","Edad": 12},{"Nombre": "JA","Apellido": "B","Edad": 12}];

var filtro = $(Data).filter(function (index,element){return element.Apellido==='B';});
 
for (var i=0;i<filtro.length;i++)
{
   console.log(filtro[i].Nombre +" "+filtro[i].Apellido)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`$(Data)` hace que la variable Data sea un objeto de `jQuery`.

`.filter` es una función de `jQuery`, directo desde su web oficial: http://api.jquery.com/filter/ dice lo siguiente:

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

Interpretado al buen español:

> Descripción: Reduce el conjunto de elementos que tienen el mismo patrón de selección.

En este caso, usamos `function(index, element)` la documentación dice:

> A function used as a test for each element in the set. this is the current DOM element

Interpretación al buen español:

> Una función es usada como prueba para cada elemento en el conjunto "this" es el actual elemento DOM.

En este caso, cada `element` representa a `{"Nombre": "AA","Apellido": "B","Edad": 12}` y como necesitamos obtener aquel elemento que tenga su propiedad (Apellido) igual a "B": `return element.Apellido==='B';`

Ahora bien, la variable filtro es un arreglo que contiene el nuevo conjunto de elementos filtrados (valga la redundancia).

Un bucle for nos permite iterar a todos los elementos y finalmente los mostramos mediante un `console.log`.

Answer (score 3):

Hola puedes utilizar [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) es nativo de JavaScript fue añadido en la especificación **ECMAScript5** por lo que esta soportado por casi todos los navegadores en la actualidad.

Para tu problema en particular es bastante sencillo, mas si lo simplificas con la nueva notación:

```
let resultado = Data.filter(obj => obj.Apellido === 'B');
```

Te invito a probar tambien [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find), que es similar pero devuelve el primer elemento que coincida con el filtro en caso que ninguno coincida devolverá `undefined`.

*Nota*: Recomendación comienza a usar `let` en ves de `var` para poder tener un mayor control sobre el ámbito de las variables que defines. Puedes leer mas acerca de [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let).

Answer (score 1):

Existen muchas formas filtrar ese Array de objetos `data`, por ejemplo:

```
var Data = [{"Nombre": "A","Apellido": "B","Edad": 12}];
var contenidoFiltrado = Data.filter((x) => (x.Apellido[0] === 'B'));
```

La variable `contenidoFiltrado`, contiene todos los los elementos del Array `data`, cuyo *`Apellido`* comienza por *`B`*.

Comment: Mmmm y si la 'B' fuera una variable? es decir que no fuera un valor fijo? He intentado tu procedimiento pero no me devuelve nada como resultado =(

Comment: Colocando una variable debería funcionar de igual modo, ten en cuenta que con x.Apellido[0], cojes solo el primer caracter del string x.Apellido, si en lugar de los que empiezan por B, quieres todos los que se apelliden Frutos, debes quitar el [0]. No se si estas teniendo eso en cuenta.

Comment: Hay un error en tu respuesta @Jcarlos, el atributo Apellido es un `string` no un array de string el filtro correcto seria `(x) => (x.Apellido === 'B')` porque sino estas filtrando por todos lo que comiencen con B

Comment: Tienes razon @RicardoD.Quiroga, no leí bien la pregunta. Buena observación.